# How to create a segue in iOS without having an associated UI Element

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I load "ViewController1" first. It does a bunch of background housekeeping work and then goes to "ViewController2".

To perform a Segue to "ViewController2", the only way I know is to add a BUTTON (which user never needs to see or use) and then add a segue from that button to the "ViewController2" by holding down control and dragging.

**My question is** -- Since I dont really need the button in ViewController1 here, how can I just create a Segue and then do it in code using **performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_LoginToStart", sender: nil)**

[image: How to perform Segue without having an associated UI Element like a Button?]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Step -1**

-- select your stoyboard name (Yellow button) in Storyboard

**Step -2**

-- Press `Ctrl + right` click -- segue to your destination view controller

[image]

**Step -3**

-- give the seque name in attribute

**Step -4**

call the following line where you want

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_LoginToStart", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click "Yellow button". (I don't know the name of this button)

[image]