# Perform segue without use of a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I want to create a segue that takes me from one view controller to another if a condition is met without the use of a button. This segue should take place once the application loads for the firs time. It would look something like this:

```
if(condition){
   //perform segue
}
```

I just don't know how to actually perform the segue. How could I do this?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176215/understanding-performseguewithidentifier) answer your question?

Comment: try this link very hope ful for you , the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294160/how-to-create-a-segue-in-ios-without-having-an-associated-ui-element/29294298#29294298

Comment: Yes it is helpful however I do not know what kind of segue I should use? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Your edit makes it an X-Y question, because you do not need a segue to choose the initial view controller.

Comment: Well I want a segue to the other view only if a condition is met. If that condition is not met, then it stays on the initial view

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that worked. If you make it an answer, I can select it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method:

```
if (condition) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

The snippet above assumes the context of an instance method in a class that defines a segue with identifier `"mySegue"`.

> This segue should take place once the application loads for the firs time.

You do not need a segue for situations when the application loads. Instead, you need to [set the initial view controller programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10428629/335858).

Comment: how do I define the segue Identifier to be mySegue or whatever I want it to be

Comment: When I looked at that website, you must use a button for the segue, but I do not want to use a button

Comment: I do not think we are on the same page. I am basically trying to do it all programmatically.

Comment: Note that the segue is not defined in the class, but the storyboard. Create the segue to go from the first view controller to the second, by selecting the first and control-dragging to the second.

Comment: It doesn't let me do that unless I am using a button

Comment: It gives me the following:

Comment: My Application[14561:3988910] Warning: Attempt to present <SWRevealViewController: 0x7b26e9a0> on <ViewController: 0x7b26d1c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: What kind of segue should it be? Should it be like modal reveal view controller or what?

Comment: Thats not what I want. Basically when the application is launched, If a certain condition is met, I need a segue that takes me from one view to the other, with no buttons or anything. To the users eyes it would look as if that view is the first view