# functionality for edit button next to delete in UITableView cells' editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented that "swipe left on a cell" functionality to reveal "Edit" and "Delete" buttons, but I am struggling to properly pass the cell's indexPathForCell, as tapping the edit button merely brings up the Add/Edit cell view, rather than pre-populating the fields in Add/Edit with data from that cell whose edit button was tapped.

Here's the relevant code from my ItemTableViewController:

```
// swipe-left options for a cell (Edit, Delete)
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
        self.items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
        // edit item at indexPath
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditItem", sender: self)
    }

    return [delete, edit]
}


// Prepare for Segue
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
        let ItemDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddItemController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedItemCell = sender as? ItemTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedItemCell)!
            let selectedItem = item[indexPath.row]
            ItemDetailViewController.item = selectedItem
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
        print("Adding new item.")
    }
}
```

The prepareForSegue function works fine if I tap on the cell itself, since that's what the segue is linked to. Ultimately, I want tapping on the cell to trigger a different segue to another view, so it actually seems I will have to scrap much/most of this implementation. I would simply right-click and drag from the Edit cell button, but it is not visible in the Storyboard, hence the current implementation of it piggybacking off of the "tap-on-cell" action, but since I want that "tap-on-cell" segue to go elsewhere, I'm totally lost as to how I'd have the edit button "get the indexPath for this cell and segue onto the Add/Edit view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditItem", sender: self)`
you should no send self, but the indexPath you received, it is the indexPath of the object you want to modify.

And in `prepareForSegue` for the segueIdentifier EditItem, you know that the sender is a NSIndexPath, so you use it (in fact, you don't have to search tableView.indexPathForCell).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mind being more specific about the code for the prepareForSegue function?

Comment: `if segue.identifier == "EditItem" {
        let ItemDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddItemController  
            let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath  
            let selectedItem = item[indexPath.row]  
            ItemDetailViewController.item = selectedItem  
        }`   and create a new segue for when taping on the Cell

Comment: Thank you, that worked! For those that don't know, here's how you'd add a segue to a UI element that you can't physically right click on in the storyboard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294160/how-to-create-a-segue-in-ios-without-having-an-associated-ui-element (just add a segue from the ViewController itself to the desired destination)